# i have this problem when i open phpmyadmin

Tags: server, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I have a problem when I open **phpmyadmin**,

When I write **myip.com/phpmyadmin** [this](http://pastebin.com/99MSbRSe) shows up instead of phpmyadmin login screen, please help.

I have tried reinstalling everything using

```
apt-get purge
```

then

```
apt-get install
```

But nothing worked.
I think its `Apache2` that is causing the problem.
I really need this so please help thanks.

Comment: it is a php file and it opens as ascii text, you are probably missing interpreter, check if you have php installed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with your Apache installation. Make sure you have installed everything properly.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and install :

1. LAMP stack

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
   ```
2. Phpmyadmin  :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
   ```

   At this step :

   [image: phpmyadmin configuration screenshot]

   Do not forget to check `apache2` with <kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select **OK**.

Comment: thanks dude i forgot to press tab i immediately pressed enter after selecting apache2